# Как закрыть chrome и chromedriver из pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, selenium-webdriver

У меня есть приложение с gui на pyqt5, оно запускает браузер, в новом потоке. Мне нужно, что бы при закрытии приложения, закрывался браузер, который запускает приложение. Пока нашёл только такой вариант, подскажите, можно ли закрывать только тот браузер, который открывается в новом потоке?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets,QtGui
import sys
import os

class PyShine_THREADS_APP(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = uic.loadUi('listWidget.ui',self)
        self.thread={}
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.start_worker_1)
    def start_worker_1(self):
        self.thread[1] = ThreadClass(parent=None,index=1)
        self.thread[1].start()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        os.system("taskkill /f /im chromedriver.exe")
        os.system("taskkill /f /im chrome.exe")

class ThreadClass(QtCore.QThread):    
    any_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    def __init__(self, parent=None,index=0):
        super(ThreadClass, self).__init__(parent)
        self.index=index
        self.is_running = True

    def run(self):
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
            

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = PyShine_THREADS_APP()
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-close-and-quit-method-in-selenium-python/

Comment: Но как это сделать при закрытии главного окна qt? это же другой поток